# Pop up the window of exsiting view through click event in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have created a `button` in jobs by using inheritance in (`hr.recruitment` form view) , how could I open another module("Resumes and Letters -sub menu in Human Resource " ) form_view during buttons click event is done.my aim is that  I just want open that form when this click event done.

Is it possible to solve? Need help please

Comment: There are many screen in odoo where you click on a button and wizard/popup is shown, try to surf through those screen and try to find how that works. example: Customer Invoice screen where you find a button to do the payment, which opens a popup. Here you just need to apply little bit of effort to search through odoo core code and you will find your answer.

Answer (score 11):

yes, it is possible to open another window. you have to do like this.

```
@api.multi
def button_method(self):
    return {
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'name': 'form name',
        'res_model': 'object name',
        'res_id': id ,
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'target' : 'new',
        }
```

but it is possible when record save. if you want to open wizard before save record you have to code in js like this.

**in js file:**
openerp.module_name = function(instance) {

```
var QWeb = openerp.web.qweb;
    _t = instance.web._t;

instance.web.View.include({
    load_view: function(context) {
        var self = this;
        var view_loaded_def;
        $('#oe_linking_e').click(this.on_preview_view_button);

 //this is button class which call method for open your form.

       return self._super(context);
    },
```

**//method which open form**

```
    on_preview_view_button: function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            this.do_action({
                name: _t("View name"),
                type: "ir.actions.act_window",
                res_model: "object",
                domain : [],
                views: [[false, "list"],[false, "tree"]],
                target: 'new',
                context: {},
                view_type : 'list',
                view_mode : 'list'
            });
        }
    },
});
};
```

in `xml` file add button and give `id="oe_linking_e"` whatever you give in `js` code.

Comment: Sorry to ask here. How can I get `view_id` dynamically on js so later i can use it as dictionary parameter on `do_action`?. I know how to do it in python but not in js.

Answer (score 5):

you can return form in this manner. 
In your button method return this dictionary. It will open the target form in a pop-up window ,

```
def button_method(...........):
    return {
              'name': _(some name),
              'view_type': 'form',
              "view_mode": 'form',
              'res_model': model-name,
              'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
              'target': 'new',
              }
```

you can pass `<br>` `'res_id': target_id` in the above dictionary to open a particular record